# iPhone SDK: How to add multiple labels to table cell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to create a custom table cell that has multiple labels. I already have code to create a custom cell. My problem is, it is just not that pretty. What I need is some pointers on how to apply multiple labels each of which may be a different color, font, etc.

These are the labels I would like to include and they should appear centered one after another.

> a.) Name b.) Address1 c.) Address2 d.)
>   Phone

Any pointers or links to examples greatly appreciated.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476600/multiple-labels-in-a-table-cell-view?rq=1?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom cell with the labels on them however you desire. It can easily be done, and I have done it before. It's not really hard, Apple has sample code on creating custom cells available on the portal that you should have a look at if you can't envision how to do this.

Comment: Yes, I am already creating custom cells but they aren't much to look at. I need some pointers on creating the labels that I will apply to the custom cell. Sorry, if that wasn't clear in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted? Replace `cell` with `self` if it is in a UITableViewCell subclass...

```
UILabel *name = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:whatever];
[name setText:@"something"];
[cell addSubview:name];
```

Comment: That is the basic idea. However, I need multiple labels.

Comment: Then do that multiple times with different variable names and different frames.